# PHP: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() - On WINDOWS

Tags: php, mysql, windows, function

Community, I'm going crazy over this error. I searched the site and although I found many answers about it (I believe I tried them all), I could not fix my problem.

**Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:\Users\Laureano\Desktop\Udemy\Web Dev\AppSalon_fin\includes\database.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **C:\Users\Laureano\Desktop\Udemy\Web Dev\AppSalon_fin\includes\database.php** on line **3**

This is what I've tried so you can cross it off the list.

1. My php.ini file has been edited in order to have:

- extension_dir set to recommended values, see here:
  [extension_dir values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi0mS.png)
- I removed the semicolon in extension=php_mysqli :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYinJ.png)
- I do have mysqli module installed as seen in this screenshot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOjFl.jpg)

Everytime I changed the .ini file I restarted the server from Windows Services: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXpYF.png)

Now, I don't really know what else to do. If you can give me a hand I would much aprecciate it.

Comment: Two things: first in the php.ini set only one extension_dir (so remove the one with just "ext"). Secondly, restart the PHP/Apache server (not the Mysql database service). To see if things are working, make a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, if you open that page it should tell you which configuration is loaded (extension_dir) and which extensions.

Comment: @ArendE - thank you for your answer. I did the first step. Now, the second part, how can I restart the apache server or where do I find it? All I'm doing step by step is: Open VSCode > Open my database.php file in the browser using a extension called PHP Server > Then It gives me that error. I never manually started an apache server nor I know how to do it. Let me know if you need any more info and thank you again.

Comment: I've never used PHP Server inside VSCode, but peeking at the documentation you should have the command "PHP Server: Reload server" available. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver

Comment: @ArendE Jesus Christ I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much, it's working now!

Comment: Good to hear so! Happy coding :)